# Lipschitz continuity and bounded derivative

Tags: analysis, derivatives

Intuitively why if a function has bounded derivative in [a,b] it's Lipschitz continuous ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the mean value theorem, suppose $x,y \in [a,b]$ with $x \neq y$:

$$\exists c \in (x,y) \text{ such that } \frac{f(y) - f(x)}{y-x} = f'(c).$$

Since the derivative is bounded, we have that $|f'(c)| \leq M$ for some $M$. Thus
 $$|f(y) - f(x)| \leq M |y-x|$$
which is precisely the condition for $f$ to be Lipschitz.

For an intuitive explanation, if you're driving along with a bounded velocity, then your change in position should be proportional to the time you've been driving.

Answer (score 0):

First, recall the definition of Lipschitz continuity:
$f:[a,b]\to \mathbb{R}$ is Lipschitz continuous if $\mid f(x)-f(y)|\leq k|x-y|$ for some $k$.

As $f$ has bounded derivative in $[a,b]$, apply the mean value theorem to complete the proof.